# Why All fields are change when execute my postlink Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

When click ,  all field status in table Req.. change to 1..

i need change status only when selected $req2['Req']['id']

What are wrong..?

My view when use postlink

```
<?php echo  $this->Form->postLink(__('C'),$this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'Reqs','action' => 'editstatus', $req2['Req']['id'])), null, __('Estas seguro de que quieres cancelar la req # %s?', $req2['Req']['id'])); ?>
```

My controller Reqs and function editstatus

```
public function editstatus($id = null) {
          if (!$this->request->is('post') && !$this->request->is('put')) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException();    }
  $this->Req->id = $id;       
if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
    $this->request->data['Req']['status'] = '1';
if ($this->Req->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Se Grabo la Requisicion'.$id);
    }   else {  $this->Session->setFlash('No se pudo cancelar la Requisicion'.$id);}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view you are calling $this->requestAction(), that means that every time that link is generated it will also call the action "editstatus".

Remove the $this->requestAction() like this:

```
<?php
    echo  $this->Form->postLink(__('C'),
          array('controller'=>'Reqs','action' => 'editstatus', $req2['Req']['id']),
          null,
          __('Estas seguro de que quieres cancelar la req # %s?',
          $req2['Req']['id']));
?>
```

Comment: works  in my localhost.. but deploy in server and dont work ..send me message..'No se pudo cancelar la Requisicion'...why...?